# Lenovo laptop suddenly shutdown an never turning back on

Tags: power-supply, battery, lenovo-laptop

I think i have a big problem.

My Lenovo G50-80 suddenly shutdown. It was connected with the charger and the battery was in good condition.
The laptop doesn't have the warranty.

I tried removing the battery multiple times with no luck, pressed and hold the power key for 30 seconds.

Even when i connect the charger the charging LED indicators are not lighting at all.

Has any one faced something like that and what are the possibilities for the problem... I just need the hard drive to be ok because i haven't done a backup for a while now.

Comment: Good news is, there is very little chance the hard drive has failed. Bad news is, it could be your motherboard. Best news would be that it is just the power adapter. Have you tried a different power adapter? Were you using the computer when it shut down? Did you notice it say the battery wasn't charging or anything?

Comment: Measure if your power supply gives voltage. Try another charger.

Comment: Assuming its a power issue, its possible your hard drive is still fine. Probably worth sticking it in an enclosure to check

Comment: Try leaving it plugged in for a few hours. Maybe the laptop was left on and fully discharged. Often laptops need to be left plugged in to gain enough charge to restart - especially if the power brick is starting to die.

Comment: Thank you all.. Yes i tried a different charging adapter and still didn't give me any sign of charging or anything... The battery was fully charged and the laptop was plugged in to the power... But i tried the hard drive and to worked... THANK GOD... But i think as @Appleoddity said... The motherboard is died... Sadly...but thank you all for trying 5o help ane thank god for the hard drive... The data inside it was worth all my work and my projects....